# unraring/unzipping a file using python+django

Tags: python, django, archive, compression, rar

I'm trying to write a distributable web app that will allow the user to upload a compressed archive (rar or zip), extract it on the server side, then do something else with the files. Is there a default library I can hook into to do this? Or is there a way to package an external library with the web app so the end user doesn't have to install that package themselves?

Answer (score 4):

[Zip is easy](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html). Rar, [not so much](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/rarfile/).